# What is the reason for this unexpected transaction ordering

Tags: extrinsic, transactions, transaction-fees, acala, karura

My understanding is that transaction priority and therefore the ordering in the block is determined by the fee and tip paid.

I have noticed a number of times that transactions with the highest total fee are not always at the top of the block. Some examples:

https://karura.subscan.io/block/1946916

https://hydradx.subscan.io/block/3857602

What could the reason for this be?

The only thing I can think of is perhaps the highest tip transaction is arriving late and for some reason the priority doesn't have time to be recalculated.

I am aware that some chains have priority rules based on the extrinsic type, but examples like this make me think this isn't the case for Hydra at least:
https://hydradx.subscan.io/block/3850710